# Conditional Autofilter over multiple fields in a single autofilter

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

I'm creating some coding for a statement of accounts macro and I'm checking if there is such a thing as a conditional autofilter over multiple fields, ie:

```
TSOA.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="Unpaid", Operator:=xlOr, Field:=9, Criteria2:=">" & Dbl3M
```

So I need entries that are either unpaid or within 3 months of this month (not mutually exclusive, so the only ones that are really filtered out are paid and older than 3 months ago). So any entries after the 28/02/2015, paid or unpaid, must be included (I know this sound complicated).

Anyway if this doesn't work, I've got some workarounds up my sleeve by autofiltering them by individual criteria, adding them both to a single array and removing duplicates! I just wanted to know the limitations of the autofilter function and whether this could actually be done. Thank you.

An illustration of how it works:

[image]

So I arbitrarily made entries up to 14/04/2015 as "Paid", The filterbutton filters up to only 3 months of data left from last month (May-2), it also must include "unpaid" entries from older than 3 months ago, and include "paid" entries within the 3 months.

Here's some of the rest of the code if it helps you understand:

```
Private Sub FilterButton2_Click()

Dim Balance As Double
Dim DblMonth As Double

With ThisWorkbook

Set TSOA = .Worksheets("SOA").ListObjects(1)
DblMonth = CLng(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0)) 'integer value of last month last day
Dbl3M = CLng(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 2, 0)) 'integer value of 3 months ago last day

If TSOA.AutoFilter.FilterMode = True Then
    TSOA.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    TSOA.ListColumns(10).DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    Exit Sub
Else: str3 = InputBox("Please input client initials", "Client filter")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Worksheets("SOA").Range("D:D"), str3) = 0 Or str3 = "" Then
    MsgBox "Client cannot be identified!", , "Error"
    Exit Sub
    End If
End If

**ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
TSOA.Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=str3
    TSOA.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="Unpaid", Operator:=xlOr, Field:=9, Criteria2:=">" & Dbl3M**

For K = 1 To TSOA.ListRows.Count

If Not TSOA.DataBodyRange.Rows(K).Hidden Then
    Balance = Balance + TSOA.DataBodyRange(K, 6).Value
    TSOA.DataBodyRange(K, 10).Value = Balance
End If
Next

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think AutoFilter works on one column (Field:=1, or Field:=8, etc). It can accept multiple criteria but limited to the value in each field

One other solution could be with formulas (if you can use a temporary column)

The formula: `=OR( B2="Unpaid", AND(B2="Paid", A2 < 4) )`

.

[image]

My Dates: 1 = This month, 2 = Last month, etc

Comment: I solved it by using autofilters to remove the paid ones, and then unhiding those that were within 3 months in a separate loop. Tedious.... but it'll be nice if autofilter had multiple criteria over different fields sometime :D

Comment: You're perseverant! Great work. Now that I think about it, criteria that cross filters would be quite helpful, instead of forcing people to be creative :) I'm not sure how you implemented it, but other might find it helpful as well

Comment: I'll post my answer then :D

Comment: Please post your answer